# SharePoint 2010 bug with .docx, .xlsx documents while uploading/opening

Tags: 2010, document-library, office-integration

By now there are many bugs out there in sp2010 integration with office documents. But, in this case if you create an empty .docx with the following word metadata SP2010 crashes while uploading these documents.Tried it with *.docx, *.xlsx only.

Name: ContentType, Type: Number, Value: =1

We are running SP2010 with OCTOBER 2011 CU.

Second part of the bug is, we have a bunch of these documents about 1500 migrated into our production environment sometime back and now when someone tries to open/download these "Corrupted documents with .DOCX or .XLSX extension" SP2010 goes crazy and app pool crashes.

I did see blogs with reference to document promotion or demotion but this still exists after 'web.parserenabled' turned off.

Any ideas on a fix or reference to support articles will be great! Please feel free to ask if you would like more details.

Comment: Apologies, disabling the parser does solve the issue, but it is indeed weird why this exact set of metadata causes issues for these extensions!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `SPWeb.ParserEnabled = false` does the work. However, be aware of that this has some disadvantages. For details check the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205913/data-disappearing-after-itemupdate-in-sharepoint-with-office-2007-documents